# PWM using XC8 compiler and peripheral libraries

Tags: pic, pwm, xc8

I am trying to run the most simple example of PWM using a ***PIC18F4550***, ***XC8 compiler*** and the libraries ***plib/timers.h*** and ***plib/pwm.h***

My code is the next:

```
#include <xc.h>
#include <plib/timers.h>
#include <plib/pwm.h>

//CONFIGURATION BITS...
#pragma config PLLDIV = 5, CPUDIV = OSC1_PLL2, USBDIV = 2
#pragma config FOSC = HSPLL_HS, FCMEN = OFF, IESO = OFF
#pragma config PWRT = OFF, BOR = OFF, VREGEN = OFF
#pragma config WDT = OFF, WDTPS = 32768
#pragma config MCLRE = ON, LPT1OSC = OFF, PBADEN = OFF
#pragma config STVREN = ON, LVP = OFF, ICPRT = OFF, XINST = OFF

#define _XTAL_FREQ 48000000

void main(){
    TRISCbits.TRISC2 = 0;
    unsigned char prescaler = T2_PS_1_16;
    OpenTimer2(prescaler);
    OpenPWM1(0x95);
    while(1){
        SetDCPWM1(300);
    }
}
```

And the diagram of my PIC is:

[image]

But I get an error message when trying to compile:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\xc8\v1.40\include\pic18f4550.h:4426: error:    (1098) conflicting declarations for variable "_TRISCbits" (C:\Program Files   (x86)\Microchip\xc8\v1.40\include\pic18f4550.h:3829)
(908) exit status = 1
nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:125: recipe for target   'dist/default/production/PWM_code.X.production.hex' failed
make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/Delfin/Pictures/PIC18F4550   Basics/PWM_code.X'
nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:84: recipe for target '.build-conf' failed
make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/Delfin/Pictures/PIC18F4550   Basics/PWM_code.X'
make[2]: *** [dist/default/production/PWM_code.X.production.hex] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target '.build-impl' failed

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 1s)
```

I have already downloaded and installed the periperial libraries from here: http://www.microchip.com/mymicrochip/filehandler.aspx?ddocname=en574973 and also linked them in my code as I show in the following picture:

[image]

So, why is not compiling? When I comment the line:

```
OpenPWM1(0x95);
```

works fine. I would appreciate any suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have solved my question.

The problem is that I was using the ***1.40 version of XC8 compiler***. The periperial libraries are not longer supported and were compiled with version ***1.34 of MPLAB XC8***. Any changes made to header files since those libraries were created could potentially create a declaration mismatch.

What I did was download the former 1.34 version of XC8 ( http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/xc8-v1.34-full-install-windows-installer.exe ) and installed it. After that I chose to work with that version of the compiler and my code now works fine

Comment: +1 but this is a huge abandonment to users by Microchip

Comment: Agreed, I have a number of projects that use 18F4550's , perfectly good MCU, and NOT supported my the new Harmony and MCC stuff, plib just makes things so much easier than having to prat about with direct register manipulation.  All MCP are interested in is getting folks on to the next new hotness so they can continue to milk profit from them.